# Preference Fragment overlaps BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

I have 4 fragment, the last fragment is Setting Fragment using Preference Fragment:

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {

   ...

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }

   ...

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        public MyPreferenceFragment(){}

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

**My problem**
With first 3 fragments, bottom navigation bar still work
But in last fragment is Setting Fragment, my fragment view overlaps my bottomNavigationView. I can not click to bottomNavigationView anymore. It relizes the click to item in fragmentView

[image: Problem with fragment and bottomNavigtaionView]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `PrefereceFragment` inside another `Fragment`?

Comment: @cmak becasue I want to use preferences for Settings, and all other is Fragment, I need to use PreferenceFragment inside SettingFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, if using `androidx` libraries

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

and a parent `Fragment` is not required if it's only a single screen, instead use the Preference Fragment directly.